# struts dialog box not taking jsp scriplet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am using `struts dialog box` in a jsp page. I want that `id` of each `dialog` box should be dynamic. For that I am doing this code -

```xml
<%
    int counter = 0;
%>
<s:iterator var="RP" value="campaignList" status="currRow">
    <%
        counter++;
    %>
    <sj:dialog id="DivQuestionAnswer<%=counter%>" autoOpen="false"
        modal="true" width="750" cssStyle="font-size: 15px;"
        title="Question Results">
        <s:form name="frmUploadQuestion" id="frmUploadQuestion"
            action="uploadQuestion" method="post" theme="simple">
            <s:hidden value="" name="question.campaignId" id="campaignId" />
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10"
                cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="45%">Question File :</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td width="55%"><input type="file"
                        name="question.questionFile" id="questionFile" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </s:form>

    </sj:dialog>
</s:iterator>
```

But it is always taking id as `DivQuestionAnswer<%=counter%>`. Not like DivQuestionAnswer1,DivQuestionAnswer2,DivQuestionAnswer3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix Scriptlets (`<% %>` , [that you shouldn't use *at all*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1654265)) with Struts tags (or Struts2-jQuery tags).

Also you don't need to: with an Iterator, you get an [IteratorStatus](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) object, that can be used as a counter:

```xml
<s:iterator value="campaignList" status="currRow">
    <sj:dialog id="DivQuestionAnswer%{#currRow.count}" ... >
```

Note: `#currRow.count` is 1-based, `#currRow.index` is 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

`"  You have put the counter inside double quotes so it will not work .

```
"\"" + <%=counter%>+ "\""
```